# java prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a requirement like this...

Need to execute a java prepared statement example:

```
String sql = "select first_name from student where roll_no :=1";
connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

But the problem is, sometimes there can be NO rows in the table for the above query.
In that case, I want to query the 2nd table say `student2`. Hence the sql query will be now:

```
String sql2 = "select first_name from student2 where roll_no :=1";
```

Is there a way to achieve this condition of selecting from another `table(student2)` in a single sql query.

I want something like this pseudo code:

```
String sql = "if student1 table doesn't have a roll_num, then query student2 table";
```

Comment: I think this is not a SQL problem, but more a issue with your database design. Maby you should rethink your databse tables, so you don't need  a query that is that complex.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database procedure which you call with the prepared statement
 [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html),
 [Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php).
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Though your design is not good, I am giving hint to achieve what you are asking. When you execute first query, just check are there any result sets available, if not then execute second query.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.execute();
if (!rs.next()){
//ResultSet is empty
}
```

In If block you need to execute second query.

Note: First rethink your design, if not possible. This solution works, a lame solution for lame problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use e.g. UNION as:

```
select val from (select 'A' as val from DUAL
                 union
                 select 'B' as VAL from DUAL)
where rownum = 1;
```

but @tbraun89 is right think on your DB structure first